# Neo4j: Adding nodes and finding relationship taking more time

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Here is my python code, I am trying to insert nodes and find relationships but it is taking more time, help will be appreciated

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, authenticate
authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "neo4j")
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
i=0;

xml_file = open("sample.xml")
xml_doc = minidom.parse(xml_file)
archives = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('archive')
class_names=xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('class')
label_Archive="Archive"
label="Class"

'Adding Nodes'
for arch in archives:
    arc = graph.create(Node(label_Archive, arc_value=arch.attributes['name'].value))
    topic_nodes = arch.getElementsByTagName('class')
    for clas in topic_nodes:
        cla=graph.create(Node(label,class_value=clas.attributes['name'].value))
       e'].value))

**Adding  relationship**
```

'This section adds relationship'

```
 for arch in archives:
        ARCID_=arch.attributes['name'].value
        node = graph.find_one(label_Archive, property_key="arc_value", property_value=ARCID_)
        for clas in topic_nodes:
             ClassID_=clas.attributes['name'].value
             node1 = graph.find_one(label, property_key="class_value", property_value=ClassID_)
             try:

                     relationship_class=Relationship(node, "Class", node1)
                     graph.create(relationship_class)
                    IndexError:
                 continue
```

Comment: please share your input data

Comment: `<PythonArchive>
  <archives>
    <archive name="test.zip">
      <class name="CallCollector" file_name="Nothing.py">
      </class>
      <class name="Walker" file_name="texasranger.py">
      </class>
     </archive>
  </archives>
</PythonArchive>`

Comment: do you have any index/constraint on the nodes you find, eg. `Archive.arc_value` and `Class. class_value ` ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger: I dont have any